# при добавлении нового GroupBox начинает съезжать при прокручивании

Tags: c#

работаю в WindowsForms и происходит такая фигня при добовлении нового  GroupBox[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grou();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    int y = 15;
    int x = 5;
    private void grou()
    {

        GroupBox d = new GroupBox();
        d.Width = 700;
        d.Height = 170;
        d.Location = new Point(x, y);
        d.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;
        y = y + 180;
        // d.Name = "groupbox" + chet;
        this.Controls.Add(d);
        Button dob = new Button();
        dob.Text = "добавить еще ";
        dob.Location = new Point(15, 130);
        dob.Width = 100;
        dob.Height = 30;
        d.Controls.Add(dob);
        dob.Click += new EventHandler(dob_CheckedChanged);
    }
    private void dob_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grou();
    }
}
```

Comment: ваша прблема [не воспроизводится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydQss.png) с вашим кодом

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл дописать она появляется когда в форме включен AutoScroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть подозрение, что при скоролинге координаты боксов меняются, потому можно, например, просто привязаться к наибольшей координате, например

```
int y = 15;
int x = 5;
private void grou()
{

    GroupBox d = new GroupBox();
    d.Width = 700;
    d.Height = 170;

    var controls = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToArray();      
    var y = controls.Any() ?  controls.Max(g=>g.Location.Y) + 180 : 15;     
    d.Location = new Point(x, y);               
    d.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;

    // d.Name = "groupbox" + chet;
    this.Controls.Add(d);
    Button dob = new Button();      
    dob.Text = "добавить еще ";
    dob.Location = new Point(15, 130);
    dob.Width = 100;
    dob.Height = 30;
    d.Controls.Add(dob);
    dob.Click += new EventHandler(dob_CheckedChanged);
}
```